# Vue.js conditional html attribute

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-router

I have `Tab.vue` which I pass an object of tab data (linked to `vue-router`). I would like to pass `exact` when required, and append this attribute to the template if it exists

`<tab :tabs="[{ text: 'Tab 1', route: 'home.tab1', exact: true }, { text: 'Tab 2', route: 'home.tab2' }]"></tab>`

and in `Tab.vue`

```
<router-link v-for="item in tabs" :to="{ name: item.route }" item.exact?>
    {{ item.text }}
</router-link>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<router-link v-for="item in tabs" :to="{ name: item.route }" :exact="item.exact">
```